# Angular 2 observable changes when source is updated

Tags: angular, asynchronous, real-time, observable, http-get

Right now I'm trying to write an rss reader based on this article: 
https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2016/09/19/angular2-rss-reader

As I see the feed comes from this:

```
return this.http.get(this.rssToJsonServiceBaseUrl + url)
            .map(this.extractFeeds)
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

Is it possible to bind it in real time? I mean if a new item/news is published to the feed then my component where I use the result will be updated automatically...
I'm thinking about it because angularfire2 is capable of this real-time binding, so when the database behind it is updated/modified then my view is just refresh without any navigation/browser refresh..

Thanks.

(as I see there is an option when I use the observable itself in the template with an |async pipe... unfortunately I can't find a proper article about the Observable itself in Angular2.. people always compare it to other things which I dont know..)

Comment: is http bidirectional ? nope. So you can't, sorry.... (You can pull regularly though)

Comment: hmm, in this case is there any working solution which should I use? It just seems too simple to use a timer and trigger the pull every X minutes..

Comment: yes, pulling many times is totally feasible, but being notified in realtime is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Http is not a bidirectional channel, you can pull on a regular basis, such a thing should be easy :

```js
const FETCH_INTERVAL = 30000; // pull every 30 secs

class MyService {

  public myFeeds: Observable < Feed[] >

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.myFeeds = Observable.timer(0, FETCH_INTERVAL)
      .switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.rssToJsonServiceBaseUrl + url))
      .map(this.extractFeeds.bind(this))
      .catch(this.handleError.bind(this))
      .share(); // share to avoid recreating an observable on every subscribtion
  }

  private extractFeeds(resp: Response): Feed[] {
    // do stuff (check for duplicates, etc...)
    return feeds;
  }

  private handleError(err) {
    // do stuff
  }

}
```